# Python - Pandas Dataframe ignore \ when importing

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import a very large CSV file (well over 25M rows) into python using pandas dataframe.

The dataframe has the following columns:
 - dest_profile
 - first_name
 - last_name 
 - id
 - con
 - company_name

Sometimes, there is a '\' within company_name (example: HPE\HPI) and it is causing an import error.  I've added **error_bad_lines=False** to my **pd.read_csv** code.  However, I want to import those rows as well.

***How do I go about skipping \ within company_name column?***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_1st_conns = pd.read_csv("D:\Downloads\LinkedIn\DataV2\1st_degree_nbrs.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
```

It thinks \ is a column deliminator. Here is the error message.

```
b'Skipping line 22813: expected 6 fields, saw 7\nSkipping line 62807: expected 6 fields, saw 7\n'
b'Skipping line 152688: expected 6 fields, saw 7\nSkipping line 170013: expected 6 fields, saw 7\nSkipping line 222565: expected 6 fields, saw 7\nSkipping line 222644: expected 6 fields, saw 7\nSkipping line 240790: expected 6 fields, saw 7\n'
```

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_csv(path, error_bad_lines=False, lineterminator='\n')`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried lineterminator='\n' but still running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a new file that has all backslashes replaced with an empty string `""` or some other replacement character.

An example snippet:

```
input_csv_filename = "original.csv"
output_csv_filename = "no_backslashes.csv"

# Read original contents
with open(input_csv_filename, 'rb') as f:
    csv_contents = f.read()

# Replace backslash with empty string
# b'\\' is the bytes literal for b'\'
csv_contents = csv_contents.replace(b'\\', b'')

# Write replaced contents to the output csv file
with open(output_csv_filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(csv_contents)
```

You can then go onto read the output csv file with your code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(output_csv_filename)
```

**Edit - 1**: Beware that this will indiscriminately replace all backslashes in your original csv file. If you're confident that there wouldn't be backslashes anywhere else, then you can use this approach.

**Edit - 2**: My bad, I initially assumed that file would not contain unicode characters. I have changed by code to now deal with the files in `bytes`.

Comment: I've tried but run into the following error:

UnicodeEncodeError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-16d7c989b637> in <module>()
----> 7     f.write(csv_contents)

     17 class IncrementalEncoder(codecs.IncrementalEncoder):
     18     def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0130' in position 23755: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I updated the code to now deal with unocde characters. Could you try it now? Again, be warned that this will replace any backslash it finds in the file.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back Nitred.  Yes, it helped.  Thank you so very much for the assistance.